# Saving and loading html input from flatfile

Tags: javascript, html, electron

```
   <div class="form-row">
     <label>
     <span>
     Input1:</span> <input type="text" id="Input1" name="Input1">
     </label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-row">
     <label>
     <span>
     Input2:</span> <input type="text" id="Input2" name="Input2" >
     </label>
   </div>
```

I am trying to save the input of these 2 fields too a .json file.
With the idea of reloading the stored data back into the input fields.

```
onSaveClick = function() {
var fs = require("fs");
var Input1 = document.getElementById("Input1").value;
var Input2 = document.getElementById("Input2").value;
var sampleObject = {

};
fs.writeFile("./object.json", JSON.stringify(sampleObject), (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    };
    console.log("File has been created");
});
```

i cant seem to figure out how to store them as a key and value:

```
var sampleObject = {
      Input1: txt,
      Input2: txt2,
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sampleObject = { Input1: Input1, Input2: Input2 }
```

Should solve your issue.

Comment: That was simple, thank you still need to figure out how to load from a file.

Comment: @user1443063 `fs.readFile` and `require('./object.json')` can do that